# Dynamic content changing like github

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic-content

I am working on quite large website, and all of it's content changing is based on `ajax`.

All of the `urls` are with slashes, no query string is being used, for example:

`http://website.com/user/john/`

So what would be the best way to make dynamic system, like `github` have, one of the most important features would have to be, that user would be able to `"go back"` or `"forward"` trough his history of browsing, just like you can do in github.

I am currently using `jquery` and also few other plugins so i would like to avoid using big frameworks.

By my understanding, concept should something like this:

```
$("a").live("click", function(event){
    //prevent from actualy loading that page
    event.stopFromRedirecting;

    //get url
    url = $(this).attr("href");

    //get new html
    $.post(url, {},
        function(response){
            $(".my_content").html(response);
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: github did a nice write up about how they achieved the "tree slider"  check it out here https://github.com/blog/760-the-tree-slider.  The HTML5 history API is a good way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax is a good start for this. It doesn't do the nice animations, but it'll do the history management and content swapping for you.